# What are Keyword-only fields in Python, and when should I use them?

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I'm having trouble understanding what their role is and when I would want to use them. I would appreciate an explanation with an example.

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html):
dataclasses now supports fields that are keyword-only in the generated **init** method. There are a number of ways of specifying keyword-only fields.

Example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class Birthday:
    name: str
    birthday: datetime.date
```